# Find if all elements in one multidimensional arrays exists in another (using a multidimensional array as a haystack)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have been trying to use some logic to be able to see if all elements in a multidimensional array (haystack) exits in another much larger haystack. My first haystack comes from a json object in the first place, and the second one is a "dot name" string, that is also converted into an array. The logic here is that I can use a string describing what I'm looking for in the json in a simple way:

Needle:

```
Array
(
    [key1] => Array
        (
            [provider] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                )

        )

    [key2] => Array
        (
            [consumer] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5
                )

            [hostname] => foo
        )

)
```

Haystack:

```
           [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1000
                    [consumer] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 5
                            [name] => test
                    [hostname] => foo
           [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1200
                    [provider] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 5
                            [name] => test
```

If the needle exists in the array the top key should be returned. So if we pretend all key->values below "key2" exists in array we should return key2. provider-id and consumer-id are not the same and there might be other key-values that might look the same, but has a different path. so if "hostname" would exists, but much deeper into array that is not a match.

The problem is that all examples I've come across either have:

- A fixed depth on the array.
- Having the needle as a string.
- Is not true multidimensional.

Is there a way this can be done? recursiveiteratoriterator did come to my mind but not sure actually how to use it, based on the above.

I've also looked at various in_array/is_array/array_map/array_filter recursive examples but they are fell a bit messy and I couldn't decide if it was worth trying to build something that would allow to crawl two arrays in a good way.

My array is quite large and contains, sadly mostly items I'm not interested in. But if I can find a way that works I'm sure I can optimize that part.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I'm confused. I don't understand what you're looking for (you might be mixing up the terms "needle" and "haystack") or what your expected result would be. Can you create a concrete, simplified example of inputs and expected output?

Comment: Understandable, you where right. The example I showed was my needle, not the haystack. If needle and haystack are identical below "key2" i expect the result of a function or class to be "key2"

Meaning consumer->id->5 and hostname->foo to both exists in array

Comment: I'm still not clear on the structure. Please edit the question to show an example of the needle (the value you're searching for) *and* an example of the haystack (the array you're searching in).

Comment: Sure, I have edited the post. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, this won't work through built-in functions. You'll have to write a custom one, since the formats aren't the same. You'll need recursion as well, if you don't know at which level you might find a match.

Comment: The format for sure is the same. It's just the root that is different. That can easily be done. Thanks for pointing out that this cant be done built-in, as if that was not already a  known fact.

Comment: The elements in the needle and the ones in the haystack are not of the same format. The haystack has more elements. If they were, direct comparison (`==`) could have been used inside a built-in function (such as `array_search`), merely wrapped into recursion. That's what I meant by my previous comment. But since they're not of the same format, the comparison will have to be "manual", checking each value individually.

Comment: Also, what about the case when all keys in your needle array are present inside the haystack? Do you expect both keys to be returned?